# Why is jquery "when promise" not working in this snippet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

```js
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var variable = false;
$.when(function(){
  console.log("This should be printed(consoled) first!");
  if(variable == false){
    variable = true;
    d1.resolve();
  }else{
    d1.resolve();
  }
  return d1.promise();
}).then(function(callback){
  console.log("The variable should be true: -> " + variable);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The function inside "$.when" should be executed before function inside "then" and it should set the value of the variable as "true". But there is a problem and its not working for some reason.

Comment: function () {...} isn't a promise. it's a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anonymous function you've placed inside `$.when` is never executed, and thus never returns a promise.

If you actually execute the function, so the promise is returned, it works fine

```js
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var variable = false;

$.when((function(){ // using an IIFE
  console.log("This should be printed(consoled) first!");
  if(variable == false){
    variable = true;
    d1.resolve();
  }else{
    d1.resolve();
  }
  return d1.promise();
})()).then(function(callback){
  console.log("The variable should be true: -> " + variable);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```